# Anchor Tag helper not producing href in .NET 5

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, .net-5, tag-helpers

I was using Anchor tag helper in .net5 but it is  not producing expected  href. I have tried to ask many people but no help.

<a asp-controller="home" asp-action="details" asp-route-id="@employee.Id" class="btn btn-primary">View</a>

produces

<a class="btn btn-primary" href="">View</a>

but It has to produce
<a class="btn btn-primary" href="/home/details/1">View</a>

I am attaching following screenshots with it

[index view page with tag helper code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8luKf.png)

[_ViewImports file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Cdkjp.png)

[Solution Explorer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0wlYA.png)

[Page Source on running](https://i.stack.imgur.com/77l6p.png)

Comment: Please **format code correctly (as code)**, **insert images directly to your question (without using links)**, and don't use images of code — paste the actual code instead.

Answer (score 0):

Two things, you need to check, firstly the asp.net core tag helper will generate the hert url based on your application route, please check your program.cs or startup.cs to make sure you have set the controller route well.

Like below:

```
app.MapControllerRoute(
    name: "default",
    pattern: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
```

If you use the wrong route or else, it will not generate the herf value like below:

```
app.MapControllerRoute(
    name: "default",
    pattern: "");
```

Result:

[image]

The second thing is , you should check your anohter tag helper to make sure it contains the another anchor tag helper which caused this issue. You could try to comment it inside the viewimports to test it.